# Case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java, expression

I'm a newbie at Java, and I kept getting the case expressions must be constant expressions error, can someone please help? This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IDlookup {
public void IDlookup(){
    String Stone = "ID - 1";
    String Granite = "ID - 1:1";
    //System.out.println("Hai"); //TESTER
    System.out.println("Please enter the block/item name here");
    Scanner IDselectO = new Scanner(System.in);
    String IDselect;
    IDselect = IDselectO.next();

    switch(IDselect){
    case Stone:
        System.out.println(Stone);
        break;
    case Granite:
        System.out.println(Granite);
    }



}

}
```

Comment: which version of java are you using?. If you are using older versions of java, you can't switch based on Strings.Also IDSelect is not initialized.

Comment: @WhoAml Yea, this is a separeate class, it was initailzed in another class :/

Comment: You may even want to change String to Enum

Comment: "Cannot convert String to Enum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, declare `Stone` and `Granite` as constants

```
public class IDlookup {
    private final static String STONE = "ID - 1";
    private final static String GRANITE = "ID - 1:1";
        ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that it just says that private and static are invalid, and will only work if I just put final. However, then when I type in Stone for instance, it doesn't print anything?

Comment: This is my main class http://pastebin.com/XRcVmTyb And I want it so that after I type IDlookup in the main class, I type Stone and it comes up with ID - 1

Comment: Still doesn't work. No errors, just nothing prints when I type Stone

Comment: If you type stone then you need to define your constant as `private final static String STONE = "Stone";`

Comment: That worked :D Thanks so much for your help, couldn't have done it without ya :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `String`s `stone` and `granite` `final` to fix your issue.

You also probably want to look up:

- Java naming conventions (Oracle link broken at the time of writing)
- [How `switch` statements work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)